# show search data in gridview of another page when search button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two page ,one search.aspx and show.aspx

in search.aspx i have 2 textbox and 1 dropdownlist of location,title,experience

now when person click on search button , if person have filled location than gridview show all data of that location,if person fill both location and title than it should show data with both condition of location and title ,and if person fill all textbox and dropdownlist  than it should show data with that location title and experience

now as i have gridview in another page so i am transferring all textbox and dropdown value to another page through querystring but it is not showing any data

and another what should be stored procedure for searching like this?

i have made something like

stored procedure-(it wrong but what it actually should be?)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE search

(
@Location nvarchar(50),
@Experience nvarchar(50),
@Title nvarchar(50)
)


AS
select * from Jobs where 
Location=@Location and
Experience=@Experience and
Title=@Title
or
Location=@Location
or
Experience=@Experience
or 
Title=@Title
```

search.aspx-

```
 protected void imgbtnsubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("show.aspx?loc,title,exp="+textloc.text+txttitle.Text+dropdownlistexperience.SelectedItem);

}
```

in show.aspx page ,it takes this this value in querystring and show perticular data in grdview

show.aspx-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dal.location = Request.QueryString["loc"];
        dal.title = Request.QueryString["title"];
        dal.exerience = Request.QueryString["exp"];
        GridView1.DataSource = bal.search(dal);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

bal-

```
 public DataTable search(portalDal dal)
{

    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("search", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", dal.location);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Experience", dal.experience);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", dal.title);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

errors- Procedure or function 'search' expects parameter '@Location', which was not supplied.

Comment: i think ..in search page

Comment: you did mistake                                            protected void imgbtnsubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("show.aspx?loc,title,exp="+textloc.text+txttitle.Text+dropdownlistexperience.SelectedItem);

}                                                                    see differences   textloc.text+txttitle.Text                                           textloc.text is in lower case                                       it should be txtloc.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your querystring isn't formatted correctly and your textloc.text should be ".Text"

```
    protected void imgbtnsubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("show.aspx?loc={0}&title={1}&exp={1}", textloc.Text, txttitle.Text, dropdownlistexperience.SelectedItem));
    }
```

Btw this is a great way to get a SQL Injection Attack.

Comment: sorry i wrote txtloc.text here without copying and pasting ,that's why it was small,btw what should be another way to avoid sql injection?

Comment: Check out this article if you are going to use query string you really need to check or scrub the inputs before allowing them into your stored procedure. There are bots on the web that just go looking for SQL Injection points. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx

Comment: thanks @Tony ,this query string formate worked and i will check out this

Comment: and can you tell anything about stored procedure?it is showing all data in gridview

Comment: Gridview AutoGenerateColumns by default is set to true which means it will show all the columns in the DataSet that you provide it. You can either Select less in your stored procedure or turn AutoGenerateColumns off and use bound/template fields. Here is a tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs

Comment: i have done same ,but still when i write location and title ,it shows all data of that location and of that title differently,it is showing like full outer join

Comment: In your SQL Statement you are using OR are you sure you don't mean AND ?

Comment: yup,if i will use "and" than all condition should satisfy than only it will show data in gridview , like location,title and experience all should be in one row but using "or" if any condition satisfies it will show data,i think "or" and "and" is not placed formatly  that is why it is not showing

Comment: When you use OR like you are the condition will be true. You need to break your conditions out or just drop the OR its not clear to me what exactly you are trying to query here but I would change you SQL statement to just "select * from Jobs where 
Location=@Location and
Experience=@Experience and
Title=@Title" and drop all those ORs off and see if that is what you are looking for

Comment: i am trying to do something like if i input location and title than it should show that location with that particular title only none other,if i input title and experience than it should show title with that experience only and same if i input location,title and experience than it should show that location with that particular title and experience only,but instead it is showing all data related to that field i input

Comment: try using "like" instead of "=" in the query

Answer (score 0):

```
    In Search Page You did mistake..
        protected void imgbtnsubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
          {
            Response.Redirect("show.aspx?loc,title,exp="+**textloc.text**+txttitle.Text+dropdownlistexperience.SelectedItem);
            }
```

txtloc.text ...it should be txtloc.Text

Comment: thanks amol,but i edited my question here so spelled wrongly,but problem was on querystring format